# setup Directory Index dynamically

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directoryindex

I'm developing a web application using php. I need to setup directory indexes for each folder dynamically. 
How can i set directory indexes other than index.php for each folder that i create in Apache?

my current folder structure is as follows:-
`localhost/cargoINT/processes/shipment/shipment.php`

I want it to become as follows when the system redirects to localhost/cargoINT/processes/shipment/shipment.php :-

```
localhost/cargoINT/processes/shipment
```

How can i get this done using php or any other ways such as .htaccess? Please elaborate

Thanks for your time and consideration

Comment: All your `index` files have always the same name as their parent folder ? Also, where is your htaccess located ? In root folder or in a subfolder ?

Comment: @JustinIurman Yes, my htaccess is located in the root folder. So wheneveer i create a folder i want the server to automatically set index file which has same name as parent folder.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2/$2\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2/$2.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `/cargoINT/processes/shipment/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cargoINT/processes/shipment/

RewriteRule ^$ shipment.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can i do it dynamically for each folder that i create? do i have to set up for each folder manually?

Comment: Is `shipment.php` found in each folder?

Comment: Given this statement in your question **How can i set directory indexes other than index.php** If other file name changes in every sub-directory then you will need similar rule like I showed above in each sub-directory.